# Azure error - connection string difficulties

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, connection-string

I am working with an mvc5 application in vs 2015.
I am getting errors whenever I attempt to access items from the database

> Login failed for user '{your_username}'.

When I go azure portal "allow access to azure services" setting is on with my client Ip address listed.
I think my connection string is not configured correctly. I can't figure out how to correctly configure it on my local machine and with azure.

I have kept my  the connection string in my web config to my  local server which worked previously:

**In my web.config**

```
<add name="IdentityDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\UserName\EduSmart_db.Mdf;          Initial Catalog=EduSmart_db;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In Azure Portal connection string

```
Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Edu;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Name;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

- How can I tell which connection string azure is using?
- Is there  a different problem i have not considered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I tell which connection string azure is using?

Azure use the second connection string. The first one(localdb) just used in your local machine. The server can not get it. You could add Azure Sql connection string name in **Context** class to specific it.

> Is there a different problem i have not considered?

You could check from these ways:

1.The firewall settings in [Azure Sql Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal). Yo could define  a
   range of ip address(like ×.×.×.0 to ×.×.×.255) instead of only one ip
   address.

[image]

2.You could check Azure sql connection string in web.configs file like
   this. It works fine on my side.

```html
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:[databasename].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[databasename];Integrated Security=False;User Id=[username];Password=[password];Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />   
   </connectionStrings>
```

If you use Code First for Azure Sql, you could add related connection string name in Context class:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext(): base("ConnectionStringName")
 {
 }
```

3.You could click **Tools>Connect to Database>Microsoft SQL
   Server**>enter your server name, username and password about Azure
   Sql. Then click **Test Connection** button  to check whether you could connect successfully.

[image]

Besides, you could refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) to learn how to access Azure Sql in your project locally.

Comment: I realized that even though the client ip address was listed right below allow azure access, I had not added a rule to allow it access.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to publish your Web app and database to Azure as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure).

To publish your web app, right-click the project and select Publish. On the create a site page provide existing SQL Azure server, database and login credentials.

Two database connections will be provided when you publish, one of them is the DBContext. When you publish the Web site with the Wizard data tables are not published.

Since you have configured firewall settings on SQL Azure, to publish the database go to the database project. Right-click the project and select Publish. On the Publish Database dialog, click on Edit and update information regarding the database on Azure. Save the profile and publish the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql InApp here is the solution :

```
public static string Connect()
        {
            //Build an SQL connection string  
            //MySqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb"));
                var ConStr = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb");
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace("Database", "database");
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace("Data Source", "server");
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace("User Id", "user");
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace("Password", "password");
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace("Source", "server");
                //ConStr = ConStr.Replace("127.0.0.1", "localhost");

                // This line split "server=localhost:[port]" in 
    "server=localhost;port=[port]
                ConStr = ConStr.Replace(":", ";port=");
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConStr);

                return sqlString.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base(SingleConnection.ConString, throwIfV1Schema: false)
```